# how to send multipart multiple file input and other input textbox data together to jersey rest service?

Tags: jquery, json, jersey, apache-commons

Hey I have a requirement to send json data with multipart file data to jersey reset service that receive that data as bean to the service and then retrieve data (both multipart file data and textbox data) through that bean's obj. there is no form tag at client side.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/data")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getInfoViaPOST(
        @FormDataParam("json") String json,
        @FormDataParam("param1") String param2) {
   ...
}
```